# Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Observable<User[]>' Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a table where I want to reflect the every CRUD operation immediately. So I've delete operation with help JSON-SERVER.  Whenever I'm doing **add/edit/delete** which is not reflecting immediately until I refresh the whole page.

Delete is an example just to understand. to resolve the issue decided to use `async` in my template like this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users2 | async">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.role}}</td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                <!-- <a routerLink="edit/{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Edit</a> -->
                <a (click)="edit(user)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Edit</a>
                <button (click)="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete-user"
                    [disabled]="user.isDeleting">
                    <span *ngIf="user.isDeleting" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
                    <span *ngIf="!user.isDeleting">Delete</span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>


export class User {
    id!: string;
    name: string;
    role!: Role;
    isDeleting = false;
}
 users2!: Observable<User[]>;

 deleteUser(id: string): any {
    const user = this.users2.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (!user) {
      return;
    }
    user.isDeleting = true;
    this.api.delete(id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(() => this.users2 = this.users2.filter(x => x.id !== id));
  }
```

is there anyother good approach is there or my above snippet requires modification?

Thanks

Comment: when you update the `users2 ` your html must be updated. so after any operation you need to assign update users2  array

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi **update users2**  array ..sorry dont understand... can you pls give more clear idea on this.?

Comment: for example in this line: `.subscribe(() => this.users2 = this.users2.filter(x => x.id !== id));` you are updating the `users2` values right? you need something like that in your add and edit method

Comment: what do you mean by `is there another good approach is there or my above snippet requires modification`? what is wrong with this approach.  this `this.users2 = this.users2.filter(x => x.id !== id))` is good way to remove from array

Comment: No im just asking.. i may not all other ways.. so asking...

Comment: Do you have any question? let me know if there is problem